# Code a jump like in the game 'Winterbells'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, adobe-edge

How would one go about coding a jump like in [this game](http://www.ferryhalim.com/orisinal/g3/bells.htm)? I've got some working code already (made in Adobe Edge) but the way it's programmed it won't start another jump while mid-air. This is what I've got atm:

```
    var velocityY = 0;
    var gravity = 0.5;
    var onGround = false;
    var fps = 60;

    function StartJump()
    {
        if(onGround)
        {
            velocityY = -13.0;
            onGround = false;
        }
    }

    function EndJump()
    {
        if(velocityY < -6,0)
            velocityY = -6,0;
    }

    var positionY = sym.$("ball").position().left;

        Loop();

        function Loop()
        {
            Update();
            setTimeout(Loop, 1000/fps);
        }

        function Update()
        {
            velocityY += gravity;
            positionY += velocityY;

            if(positionY > 730)
            {
                positionY = 730;
                velocityY = 0;
                onGround = true;
            }
            sym.$("ball").css("top", positionY + "px");
            console.log(velocityY);
        }
```

The top value 730 is where "ball" starts on the ground. StartJump() is called on the event 'mousedown' and EndJump() on 'mouseup'. I can't figure out how to change the code so I can make it jump while mid-air (as in when it collides with sth, like how in the game the bunny hits the bell).

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, but what about replacing the boolean onGround by a integer jumpCount (or even an enum for that matter, with OnGround, FirstJumpDone and SecondJumpDone)?

Comment: You need an else statement in StartJump; currently it will only perform the jump if onGround is true, and there's no supporting logic when otherwise

Comment: @cejast Aha that makes sense, I'll try figure out what to put in there, thanks!

Comment: @cejast I have added this: `else if(jumpPosition != 730)
            {
                velocityY = -13.0;
                onGround = false;
            }` where jumpPosition is the top value of "ball". This works!

Comment: @Piegie Since it's performing the same logic you could also just rewrite the original statement as `if(onGround || jumpPosition !== 730)`